# MVC API controller processing POST request

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-mvc

Do I need to restructure for readability?

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]BoatProperties props)
    {
        // model validation
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // check if guid is set, else set it; don't set when user is admin
            if(props.Guid == null && !User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                props.Guid = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey as Guid?;
            }

            Boat boat = BoatProvider.GetBoat(props.Guid);

            try
            {
                // can't find existing boat: create new boat
                if (boat == null)
                {
                    boat = new Boat(props);
                    BoatProvider.AddNew(boat);
                }
                // otherwise update existing boat
                else
                {
                    BoatProvider.Update(boat);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                // error while updating/adding model
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            }
            // everything ok!
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, BoatProvider.GetBoat(props.Guid));
        }
        // validation failed
        return CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadGateway);
    }
```

As you can see I'm exiting all those conditions with a `return` statement. If I restructure my code like this:

```
if(!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadGateway);
}
if (props.Guid == null  && !User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    props.Guid = guid;
}
```

I will have less indentations and it may be more readable and all the steps seem more distanced from each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd certainly try to reduce the indentations, not in the least because in the case of `if(ModelState.IsValid)` it involves a 30-line block, and the `else` is just a single line. Also: [if you're going to fail, do it fast](http://joeduffyblog.com/2014/10/13/if-youre-going-to-fail-do-it-fast/).

But there are other issues to consider.

- You expect an `Exception` to happen when you create or update a `Boat`? That seems odd.
- I understand the `GetBoat` then `AddNew` vs `Update` logic, but I'd move that out of the Controller and into a Business layer. Keep your Controllers clean. Right now this is a fairly simply operation and already there are twenty or so lines. Just imagine the mess it'll become once you need to do more complicated operations.
- I'm also a bit mystified by the logic WRT the update: you retrieve the `boat` and then you do `BoatProvider.Update(boat);` -- shouldn't you have done something with that `boat` first?
- Most/all of your comments are superfluous. [Comments shouldn't tell me *what* is happening (that's what your code your do), but *why*.](http://blog.codinghorror.com/code-tells-you-how-comments-tell-you-why/)

Comment: thanks for your answer, those two articles were actually quite helpful in my case! I will reorganize my code and reduce unnecessary comments.